# Prevent NestedScrollView scrolls to top automatically

Tags: android, android-support-design, nestedscrollview

I have `ListView` inside `NestedScrollView` (do not want use RecycleListView) in my fragment. List adapter inits in `onCreate` and not recreated when app back to the fragment from other fragment. But my NestedScrollView then scrolls to the top (can I prevent this?). Without `NestedScrollView` my ListView stay at the same position.

Answer (score 2):

You should retain the list status in `onPause()` method on the Fragment (save it to the Bundle) and then read and set it in `onResume()`. Just create some constant key, save then read :-)

The value you will want to save is `getScrollY()` most probably. Then you will want to restore it with `scrollTo(int x, int y)` where x=0 and y=savedValue.

Also, you **do** want to use `RecyclerView` :-) It is really cool and works really well with `NestedScrollView` and `CoordinatorLayout`. Also, it is much easier and quicker to implement than `ListView` once you get the hang of it. It is also very lightweight. And I had once seen it save a puppy from a fire. RecyclerView is da man! :-D

Answer (score -1):

Remove @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior form the NestedScrollView layout.