# Why does Scrollview automatically scrolls to the top

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a Scrollview and items ( EditTexts, TextViews and Spinners ) inside it. So when I programatically update values in EditTexts Scrollview automatically scrolls to the top. The question is how can I prevent that autoscroll ?

Comment: kindly check while updating the values the focus is on which component?

Comment: so use `scrollTo`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38438576/5241603.

Comment: set `isFocusable()` false to the items that you update the value in the last

Comment: Thank You all, will try all answers now :)

Answer (score 0):

use scrollview.setEnabled(false) before update values in EditTexts and after update scrollview.setEnabled(true)

Comment: I do not think that it is possible, since EditTexts get updated automatically ( ~ every second ) when sensor values get changed.